# Entity Framework Core doesn't validate data when saving?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core

I have the following remote validation rule:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult ValidateWindowEndDate(DateTime? endDate, DateTime? startDate)
{
    int minWeeks = 8;

    if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue
            && (endDate < startDate.Value.AddDays(minWeeks * 7)))
    {
        return Json(data: $"Inspection window end date must be at least {minWeeks} weeks after start date.");
    }

    return Json(data: true);
}
```

That's linked to a property in my class as follows:

```
[Required]
[Remote("ValidateWindowEndDate", "InspectionWindow", AdditionalFields = "StartDate")]
public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
```

When I enter an invalid data in my view, the validation occurs as expected. But, if I get an instance of the object in code, then change the date to an invalid one and save it back to the database, e.g.

```
luInspectionWindow.EndDate = luInspectionWindow.StartDate.AddDays(1);
_context.Update(luInspectionWindow);
await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

then the save takes place without an exception and the validation method is never called, which wasn't the behaviour I was expecting. I thought EF would reject the record as invalid? Is this the expected behaviour?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, this turns out to be a change in the way EF works in Core.  It now no longer does validation at all, that is left up to the Client and server (via `Model.State`).  [Rowan Miller explains that decision in the EF repo](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/5224) as follows:

> In EF Core we dropped doing validation since it is usually already
>   done client-side, server-side, and then in the database too.

I can't use the model state in my particular scenario, so instead I've tried to get Remote validation working manually via the `Validator` object, but I'm not having any luck with that either.  More on that in this question: [Validator.TryValidateObject does not call Remote validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426916/validator-tryvalidateobject-does-not-call-remote-validation).