# Validator.TryValidateObject does not call Remote validation

Tags: c#, .net-core, data-annotations

I have a class with a remote validation data annotation as follows:

```
public partial class LuInspectionWindow
{
    [Required]
    public int InspectionWindowId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [DataType(DataType.Date)]
    public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Remote("ValidateWindowEndDate", "InspectionWindow", AdditionalFields = "StartDate")]
    public DateTime EndDate { get; set; }
}
```

That calls this annotation:

```
[AcceptVerbs("Get", "Post")]
public IActionResult ValidateWindowEndDate(DateTime? endDate, DateTime? startDate)
{
    int minWeeks = 8;

    if (startDate.HasValue && endDate.HasValue
            && (endDate < startDate.Value.AddDays(minWeeks * 7)))
    {
        return Json(data: $"Inspection window end date must be at least {minWeeks} weeks after start date.");
    }

    return Json(data: true);
}
```

If I invalidate the object and then validate it as follows I only get one error, for the null Description (which is marked `Required`), the remote validation is not checked at all.

```
luInspectionWindow.EndDate = luInspectionWindow.StartDate.AddDays(1);
luInspectionWindow.Description = null;

var context = new ValidationContext(
    luInspectionWindow, serviceProvider: null, items: null);

var results = new List<ValidationResult>();

var isValid = Validator.TryValidateObject(luInspectionWindow, context, results);

await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
```

The remote validation works fine from the view, so it is wired up correctly.  Is `Validator.TryValidateObject` expected to check remote validations?

Comment: I think it's by design. Remote validation isn't expected to be called from server (and how to do that?)

Comment: @tomRedox: I am hitting the same issue. Did you find a good way to work around this issue?