# How to disallow default value in EF Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, entity-framework-core

I am sorry for making probably a duplicate question, but for some reason I am having a hard time finding answer for my question

How to mark entity's property to always have value while it is non-nullable?

Example:

```
public class ExampleEntity
{
    // How to mark that this column cannot be a default decimal value?
    [Required]
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
}
```

The column definition in generated EF migration looks like this:

```
...
Amount = table.Column<decimal>(type: "numeric", nullable: false)
...
```

This is still allowing me to pass 0 as a value for this column. How to disallow this?

P.S.: I am using PostgreSQL

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43426175/entity-framework-core-doesnt-validate-data-when-saving - https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/5224

Comment: We do this with FluentValidation and plug it in as middleware.